# How do I setup IdP initiated sign on with a B2C Local account to Salesforce?

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

**I am trying to have an IdP initiated sign on with a B2C Local account to Salesforce.**  Under my current configuration when I navigate to my IDP to login, I receive the following error: "AADB2C90250: SAML IDP initiated SSO is not enabled for this policy."

I have ensured that `<Item Key="IdpInitiatedProfileEnabled">true</Item>` under the technicalprofile in my custom policy.  I'm not sure what other configuration to check and am looking for suggestions.

I'm using Azure AD B2C as IDP and Salesforce as IDP.  Originally it was created for SP.
For PartyEntity I'm using the same endpoint for SalesForce.  Do I need a different end point or can I use the same one?  Here's an example of my configuration.

I have a new  setup for IDP initiated and have referenced that policy below.

```
<Item Key="PartnerEntity">https://<MY_SALES_FORCE_ACCOUNT>.my.salesforce.com/.well-known/samlidp/<API_POLICY>.xml</Item>
 <Item Key="IssuerUri">https://<MY_DOMAIN>.b2clogin.com/<MY_DOMAIN>.onmicrosoft.com/<POLICY_NAME></Item>
```

Any other clues on this error would be helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

•   Please check whether a SAML response signature is created properly or not and the certificate created to sign the SAML messages is proper or not with samlp:Response message element in the SAML message or not.

•   If you don't already have a policy key, create one. Then configure the SamlMessageSigning metadata item in the SAML Token Issuer technical profile. StorageReferenceId must reference the policy key name.

•   Make sure the technical profile and application use the same signature algorithm and the algorithm supports your certificate.

•   Make sure the SAML service provider set the WantAssertionsSigned to true. If it's set to false or doesn't exist, the assertion section won't be signed.

•   Make sure you specify the certificate to be used to sign the SAML assertions sections of the SAML response. Also, check the SamlAssertionSigning metadata item in the SAML Token Issuer technical profile where StorageReferenceId must reference the policy key name.

•   Make sure encryption is enabled in the Azure AD B2C policy and the public key must exist in the SAML application's metadata endpoint with the KeyDescriptor use value set to Encryption.

•   Also, make a note that scenarios where the initiating identity provider is an external identity provider federated with Azure AD B2C, such as Active Directory Federation Services or Salesforce is not supported and IdP initiated flow is supported only for local account authentication in Azure AD B2C.

Please check the below links for more information and the sample code for IdP initiated SAML single sign on: -

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/saml-sp/tree/master/policy/SAML-SP-Initiated

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider-options?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-service-provider?tabs=windows&pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: While I don't know that this will fix my issue, I will mark it as the answer as it has a lot of ideas for me to doublecheck and good references.  Thanks!